# Add a field to DRF generic list view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to create a DRF list view that shows each course along with a boolean field signifying whether the user requesting the view is subscribed to the course.

Course subscriptions are stored in the following model:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(
      CustomUser, related_name='subscriptions', null=False, 
      on_delete=CASCADE)
   course = models.ForeignKey(
      Course, related_name='subscriptions', null=False,
      on_delete=CASCADE)

   class Meta:
      ordering = ['course', 'user']
      unique_together = [['user', 'course']]
```

This is the view I am writing:

```
class CourseListView(generics.ListAPIView):
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
   queryset = Course.objects.all()
   serializer_class = CourseSerializer
   
   def isSubscribed(self, request, course):
      sub = Subscription.objects.filter(
         user=request.user, course=course).first() 
      return True if sub else False

   def list(self, request, format=None):
      queryset = Course.objects.all()
      serializer = CourseSerializer(queryset, many=True)
      return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am looking for a way to modify the `list` method, so as to add to the response the information about whether `request.user` is subscribed to each of the courses.

The best solution I have for now is to construct `serializer` manually, which would look (at the level of pseudo-code) something like this:

```
serializer = []
for course in querySet:
    course['sub'] = self.isSubscribed(request, course)
    serializer.append(CourseSerializer(course))
```

I suspect there should be a better (standard, idiomatic, less convoluted) way for adding a custom field in a list view, but could not find it. In addition, I am wondering whether it is possible to avoid a database hit for every course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

just change your queryset in your view:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class CourseListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        subquery = Subscription.objects.filter(user=request.user, course=OuterRef('id'))
        return Course.objects.annotate(sub=Exists(subquery))
```

and add a field for it in your serializer:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sub = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: It seems that the central piece here is `annotate` (which I did not know about). However, it can only be used with aggregate functions. Is there a more general way of adding a field, whereby I can use any callable object to compute the field's value, such as my `isSubscribed` method?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate "Annotates each object in the QuerySet with the provided list of query expressions. An expression may be a simple value, a reference to a field on the model (or any related models), or an aggregate expression (averages, sums, etc.) that has been computed over the objects that are related to the objects in the QuerySet."

Comment: as for the first comment, no not just aggregate functions, you can use it with query expressions.  also adding computational field to the response can be done in so many ways like using virtual fields in the model or method fields in the serializer and etc. it really depends on the use case.

Comment: One more observation. Since you add a field to `CourseSerializer`, this class is now tightly coupled with this particular query set. Wouldn't it then make sense to define this serializer class inside `CourseListView`?

Comment: yeah, you are right. but i prefer to find a work around and reuse that serializer in other places. like in this case you can make this new field not required. `sub = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True, required=False)`